# Find all table column constraints that reference a function

Tags: sql-server

I have multiple tables that use a scalar function in a column's check constraint. Some tables use the same function in more than one column. These constrains obviously all have different names.

I need to alter this function, however first I must remove all constraints that reference it.

Is it possible to get a list of tables and and columns that references this function as a constraint, based on the functions name?

---

In an ideal world, the name of the constraints would all contain the he name of the function they reference, however unfortunately this is not the case with my database.

Comment: [`sys.sql_expression_dependencies`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-expression-dependencies-transact-sql) is your friend.

Comment: I never knew this existed, and it looks like it's a game changer! Thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this script :

```
select s.name as constraintName,c.name as ColName,o.name as TableName 
from sys.check_constraints s
            join sys.all_columns c on s.parent_object_id=c.object_id and s.parent_column_id=c.column_id
            join sys.objects o on o.object_id=c.object_id
where s.definition like '%your function name%'
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. In fact, sys.check_constraints doesn't return anything...?